Link to previous issue in a Mailchimp campaign
I'm working on an email series in my Mailchimp audience. The series has 4 campaigns (4 emails) sent a week apart. In the 2nd, 3rd, and last emails, I want to link to the previous email. If I use the generic archive email, it takes me to a non-personalized email that has the right text minus the variable parts, notably the person's name. So, rather than saying Hello Alice, it says Hello <<first name>>. And that's pretty understandable given there's nothing in the URL that would indicate who the user is.
I noticed in some URLs, the presence of a query parameter called e with a value e.g. a47gha3. That parameter actually resolves the variables in my email. So that's what I need.
This means that my email for week 2 should contain the link to my previous email to which I should append ?e=<user_identifier>. When I compose my email, is there a variable I should be using?
Thanks
